# Jquery start on hide and show a certain number of elements on a search filter

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to start by hiding the p elements, then on a search I want to only display the first 2 rows. For example if I typed in 2 into the search box it would hide Example 1 and Example 1 and show Example 2 and Example 2. If I typed in 1 into the search box it would hide Example 2 and Example 2 and show Example 1 and Example 1. if I typed X into the search box it would only show 2 Examples (I don't care which ones).

```
<input type="text" id="tableAgain">

<div id="tableAgain2">



    <p>Example 1</p>


    <p>Example 1</p>

    <p>Example 2</p>



    <p>Example 2</p>



</div>

</body>

</html>

$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("p").hide();
    $("#tableAgain").on("keyup", function() {
                var value = $("#tableAgain").val().toLowerCase();
                var txt = $('#tableAgain');  
                if (txt.val() != null && txt.val() != '') {
                    $("p:nth-child(1)").show();
                    $("p:nth-child(2)").show();
                    $("p:nth-child(3)").hide();
                    $("p:nth-child(4)").hide();
                    $("p").filter(function() {
                        $("p").toggle($("p").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                    
                    
            }); 
                    } else {  
                     $("p").hide(); 
                   

                }  
            });
});
```

Comment: This is what I tried and it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a filtered search input field.  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp

Comment: @TemidayoDtuzzyOmotayo I have looked at this and it doesn't show how you would only present a fixed number of rows. If I type in O in that example I only want to display About, Blog, and Contact on 3 rows, and hide Custom, Support, and Tools. That's my question.

Comment: Your question is not sounding feasible, why can't  <p> be <li> ?? You might have to restructure the code.

Comment: @TemidayoDtuzzyOmotayo I am asking because if you create a search box for a website and you have thousands of options, you only want the user to see 7 or 8 of those options. And as the search gets more detailed the non matched options get filtered out and the matched options get filtered in. If major companies can do it I'm sure it's feasible.

Comment: Anything is feasible in programming trust me I know but sometimes we just need to make do with the information available to us and there will always be time for an upgrade.  Filtered search isn't a bad idea as big companies use it. My aim is to help solve the problem and not figure out how big companies work.

Comment: @TemidayoDtuzzyOmotayo I agree. I guess I don't have enough experience to know how to make those upgrades. Thank you for taking the time to look at my problem.